# Add order quantities to give number ordered per product

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below SQL which lists all my order lines and the quantity of the product in that orderline.

```
SELECT p.externalReference as KitNumber, 
       p.description as Kitname,
      (SELECT quantity 
         FROM order_line 
        WHERE id = ol.id) as KitQtyShipped
  FROM order_line ol 
  JOIN shipment s ON ol.shipmentId = s.id
  JOIN product p ON ol.productId = p.id
  JOIN order_item oi ON s.orderItemId = oi.id
 WHERE s.state = 'despatched' 
   AND ol.quantity != 0
 ORDER BY KitNumber DESC;
```

which gives output like

```
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------+
| KitNumber | Kitname                  | KitQtyShipped |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------+
| 269588    | product2                 |            30 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             3 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             3 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             3 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             4 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             4 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             2 |
| 269291    | product1                 |             1 |
| 269290    | product3                 |             2 |
| 269290    | product3                 |             3 |
| 269290    | product3                 |             2 |
| 269290    | product3                 |            10 |
| 269290    | product3                 |             3 |
| 269290    | product3                 |            26 |
| 269290    | product3                 |             1 |
| 269290    | product3                 |            11 |
| 269290    | product3                 |             5 |
```

What I need is to group this by the KitNumber so that a single row is given for each kit with the grand total for the number of kitsQtyShipped. i.e all the rows above added together for each kit

I have tried:

```
SELECT p.externalReference as KitNumber, 
       p.description as Kitname,
       COUNT(*) * (SELECT quantity 
                     FROM order_line 
                    WHERE id = ol.id)  as KitQtyShipped
  FROM order_line ol 
  JOIN shipment s ON ol.shipmentId = s.id
  JOIN product p ON ol.productId = p.id
  JOIN order_item oi ON s.orderItemId = oi.id
 WHERE s.state = 'despatched' 
   AND ol.quantity != 0
 GROUP BY ol.productId
 ORDER BY KitNumber DESC;
```

but that doesn't give the right value

The output im looking to get it something like:

```
+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| KitNumber | Kitname                  | KitQtyShipped            |
+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 269588    | product2                 |(Sum of all orderlines) 30|
| 269291    | product1                 |                       45 |
| 269290    | product3                 |                       63 |
```

Comment: Is hard to help you if you don't show us what is the right value. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Zac Pls post desired output based on sample data you posted

Comment: @etsa added desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be easier than you expect (Pls check it, because I could not test it as I haven't create table script):
I just added SUM, GROUP BY on your first query:

```
SELECT p.externalReference as KitNumber, 
       p.description as Kitname,
       SUM(ol.quantity) as KitQtyShipped
  FROM order_line ol 
  JOIN shipment s ON ol.shipmentId = s.id
  JOIN product p ON ol.productId = p.id
  JOIN order_item oi ON s.orderItemId = oi.id      
 WHERE s.state = 'despatched' 
   AND ol.quantity != 0
 GROUP BY p.externalReference, p.description
 ORDER BY KitNumber DESC;
```

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: You probably dont need `AND ol.quantity != 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
SELECT p.externalReference as KitNumber, 
       p.description as Kitname,
       SUM(quantity) as KitQtyShipped
  FROM order_line ol 
  JOIN shipment s ON ol.shipmentId = s.id
  JOIN product p ON ol.productId = p.id
  JOIN order_item oi ON s.orderItemId = oi.id
 WHERE s.state = 'despatched' 
   -- AND ol.quantity != 0  -- no need this to SUM
 GROUP BY p.externalReference, p.description
 ORDER BY KitNumber DESC
```

But again without source data and expected output is just a guess.

I see you dont use `order_item`. This should also work:

```
SELECT p.externalReference as KitNumber, 
       p.description as Kitname,
       SUM(quantity) as KitQtyShipped
  FROM order_line ol 
  JOIN shipment s ON ol.shipmentId = s.id
  JOIN product p ON ol.productId = p.id      
 WHERE s.state = 'despatched' 
 GROUP BY p.externalReference, p.description
 ORDER BY KitNumber DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to set to temp table then sum and count there. Forgive me if some of the MYSQL syntax aren't right.

EDIT: If you are looking at the grand total of the KitShipped, you want to use SUM GROUP BY KitNumber and not COUNT.

```
--Create a temp table for your SQL query
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SumTable AS 
 (SELECT 
 p.externalReference as KitNumber, 
 p.description as Kitname,
 (SELECT quantity from order_line WHERE id = ol.id)  as KitQtyShipped

 FROM order_line ol 
 JOIN shipment s ON ol.shipmentId = s.id
 JOIN product p ON ol.productId = p.id
 JOIN order_item oi ON s.orderItemId = oi.id
 WHERE s.state = 'despatched' AND ol.quantity != 0)

 --Do your sum here.

 Select Sum( KitQtyShipped) as TotalShipped, KitNumber from Sumtable
 Group by KitNumber
```